# PHP How do I read the form variables with empty square brackets in their name

Tags: php, form-data

In my php file when I submit I'm able to read the following variables quite easily (see attached picture)

[image]

```
$mobile = $_REQUEST['mobile'];  
$about = $_REQUEST['about'];  
$comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];
```

Now my question is.. how do I read the "`category[]`" form value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read it like you read normal variables.

```
$category = $_REQUEST['category'];
```

Unlike other variables it will return you **PHP Array**. You can iterate over this variable just like normal **PHP Array**.

```
foreach($category as $cat) {
    echo $cat;
}
```

> Make sure your check if request actually have the value you're looking for by using **[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)**. Otherwise above code might throw undefined indexed error.

Comment: So I should use "category" and NOT "category[]"?

Comment: Last question. How do I assign it to a comma separated list? I basically need it to be something like $category = "value1, value2". I apologise but I'm currently coding without PHP installed

Comment: `$category = implode(', ', $_REQUEST['category']);`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['category'] as $category) {
    var_dump($category);
}
```

Get array variable

```
$categories = $_REQUEST['category'];
var_dump($categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this'll also show you the index or keys if you need

```
print_r ($_REQUEST['category']);
```